# CodeCommit not outputing expected environment variables to CodePipeline namespace

Tags: environment-variables, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to setup a pipeline through the AWS web console. The whole thing runs smoothly, but I have a problem with the varaibles outputted by CodeCommit that should be available to the following actions.

In the CodeCommit action configuration, the Variables namespace is set to `SourceVariables`.
[image]

In the CodeBuild action configuration, I defined a `BRANCH` environment variable supposed to map `BranchName` of the `SourceVariables` namespace, which should be outputted by the CodeCommit action based on [this variable reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html).
[image]

The `BRANCH` substitution works in CodeBuild... and yet.

[image]

This is hardly what I expected.

**What am I missing in order to CodePipeline to value this environment variable from CodeCommit as expected?**

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image you provided is from the CodeBuild configuration page, but you need to set your environment variable in the CodePipeline Action configuration page.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the value of that variables in the S3Deploy action, have you tried using env/exported-variables in your buildspec.yml file?

More information available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.env.exported-variables)

Comment: No, it's not used in the S3Deploy action, I configured the deploy action to simply get everything from the BuildArtifact regardless of file name.